# Unhandled Promise rejection, No provider for a Service

Tags: angular

I'm using a third-party npm package. This package contains an `ApiModule` with this code:

```
import { PlansService } from './api/plans.service';
import { UsersService } from './api/users.service';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [],
  exports:      [],
  providers:    [ PlansService, UsersService ]
})
export class ApiModule {
    public static forConfig(configuration: Configuration): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: ApiModule,
            providers: [ {provide: Configuration, useValue: configuration}]
        }
    }
}
```

In my Angular2 app, I'm using a main `AppModule` + `AppComponent` and a `LoginModule` + `LoginComponent`.

This is the code of `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [
    App,
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    BrowserModule,
    ApiModule,   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })
  ],
  providers: [
    ENV_PROVIDERS,
    APP_PROVIDERS
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
```

As you can see `LoginModule` is loaded by route. This is the code of `LoginModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AlertModule,
    ApiModule,   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ]
})
export default class LoginModule {
  static routes = routes;
}
```

In my `LoginComponent` I'm trying that `UsersService` is injected as a constructor parameter. Nevertheless, it's telling me:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for UsersService!

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private commty: UsersService) { ... }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to inject userService into the LoginModule, then you have to add it as a provider in the Loginmodule.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AlertModule,
    ApiModule,   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
providers: [UsersService ]
})
export default class LoginModule {
  static routes = routes;
}
```